# How to call method from controller by clicking on link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to resend activation link to user if he lost former email with this link.

So, I checked user status in Login method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            bool isConfirmed = (model == null) ? false : WebSecurity.IsConfirmed(model.UserName);
            string errorMsg = "Login or password is incorrect.";

        if (isConfirmed)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (WebSecurity.UserExists(model.UserName))
            {
                errorMsg = "Your account is not activated. Click <a href=\"" + Url.Content("~/Account/ResendConfirmationLink") + "?id=" + model.UserName +"\" class=\"alert-link\">here</a> for resend email with activation link.";
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", errorMsg);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Above code generate link like `http://localhost:64612/Account/ResendConfirmationLink?id=nickname` so by clicking on it we should call following method (from Account controller):

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ResendConfirmationLink(string id)
        {
            using (ChatContext chatContxt = new ChatContext())
            {
                var tsqlQuery = string.Format("SELECT [ConfirmationToken] FROM [webpages_Membership] WHERE [UserId] IN (SELECT [UserId] FROM [User] WHERE [UserName] LIKE '{0}')", id);
                string confirmationToken = chatContxt.Database.SqlQuery<string>(tsqlQuery).First();
                tsqlQuery = string.Format("SELECT [Email] FROM [User] WHERE [UserName] LIKE '{0}'", id);
                string email = chatContxt.Database.SqlQuery<string>(tsqlQuery).First();
                SendEmail(email, confirmationToken);
            }
            return View("Login");
        }
```

But method `ResendConfirmationLink()` is never called! Login view is reloaded and url is transform to `http://localhost:64612/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fResendConfirmationLink%3fid%3dusername1&id=username1`.

What I'm doing wrong? Why method is not calling by clicking on link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `[AllowAnonymous]` annotation to your `ResendConfirmationLink` action.

It wants the user to be authenticated before it calls that method, which you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

You are making two mistakes  as following

1. First of all you have to add [AllowAnonymous] attribute to the ResendConfirmationLink method.
2. You need to change your resedconfirmation url

   ```
   http://localhost:64612/Account/ResendConfirmationLink?username=nickname
   ```

to

```
      http://localhost:64612/Account/ResendConfirmationLink?id=nickname
```

Comment: second mistake is just a copy-paste lapse, sorry I will edit my post and change it. Anyway thanks for solutions to first error.